# How to retain site collection URL in migration office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

We need to migrate SharePoint2013 On premise to O365.

However URLs changing are a concern, how we can use our existing site collections URLs which we are using on premise.

Current URL:

https://CompanyName.com/sites/abc

https://CompanyName.com/sites/xyz

We cannot change URLs because a lot of users are depending on it.

Comment: You are going from a totally controlled environment to a hosted provider, get used to not getting everything you want. If you can't handle that, upgrade on prem, otherwise spend a lot investing in change readiness activities, like awareness of url changes feature and functionality changes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change it, then SharePoint Online likely isn't the best solution for you. You don't get a choice with SharePoint Online, it is always https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteCollection...

You could build a redirect service which can be a simple HTTP 302 redirect via IIS which evaluates the domain part and the path part of the URL and redirects the user appropriately. This will not work in all scenarios.